# How to modify only timecodes but not other numbers or letters in a text file?

Tags: c++, file-io, subtitle

I'm making a program to speed up and slow down parts of videos, and I want to support modifying times on subtitles to match. How can I search for only the timecodes in a text file and modify them?

This is for srt subtitle files. Timecodes are in the format of `HH.MM.SS,mmm`. The files contain other numbers (eg in hex colors) so I only want to search for numbers in the specific timecode format.

I already have a function to take an input time in seconds and return an output time in seconds. It should also be fairly easy to convert between 'timecode' format and time in seconds.

This is an example of the text file:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:09,138
<font color="#CCCCCC">alexxa</font><font color="#E5E5E5"> who's your favorite president</font>

2
00:00:04,759 --> 00:00:12,889
<font color="#E5E5E5">George Washington</font><font color="#CCCCCC"> has my vote Alexa</font>
```

The only thing left is **how to take in only timecodes and then replace them with new timecodes?**
Not sure where to go from here. It would also be good to avoid looping through the text file more than necessary because there will be a lot of timecodes to change.

Comment: While you can modify a file in place if the characters being replaced are EXACTLY the same number as the original -- but it is best to avoid that scenario as it is fragile. Better to read the file into memory make the changes and write the new file out.

Answer (score 1):

Given it's a text format, the most efficient way to match (and replace) the format of the time-stamps in your file would be to use regular expressions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

the algo would you like this: you read line by line from your source file, for
every read line where RE matches, you replace it with the new time-stamps (i.e. craft a new line) and output to a new file (or to a buffer, which later could be committed into the source file - after processing is done). Other lines (where RE does not match) you output intact, as they were read.